# C# Read Specific Line in Test

Tags: c#, string

I'm using an api that returns results like this:

[image]

> OK
>
> 66443010

http://getclicky.com/help/api/whitelabel

Using C# what is the best way to get the value of a specific line, like the 2nd line.
I just want the "500"

Comment: Can you guarantee that there will be no whitespace within the value on each line?

Comment: Are you reading this from a stream, a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be as simple as this (assuming that the lines are separated with `"\n"`, you should check this with your return value):

```
var lines = result.Split("\n");
var code = lines.Length >= 2 ? lines[1] : null;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Environment.Newline` instead of `"\n"`?

Comment: @SteveGreatrex: No -- `Environment.NewLine` depends on *your* system. There's no guarantee that the remote API uses the same definition of "newline" as your system does.

Comment: Good point, but doesn't that mean that we are assuming that the remote API is using `"\n"`?  Would we not be better off using something like `Regex.Split(result, @"[\r\n]+")`?

Comment: @SteveGreatrex: We 'd be better off using whatever the remote API does, that's why I wrote "you should check this".

Answer (score 1):

The example below uses regular expressions to split the string based on every occurence of a sequence of carriage return or newline characters:

```
var segments = Regex.Split(myText, @"[\r\n]+");
```

From this you can just grab whichever segment you want by indexing the result, and it doesn't rely on any specific newline character from the remote API.

This approach also has the advantage of removing any blank lines from the `segments` array, which (presumably) you aren't interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Use ReadLine() of StreamReader or File.ReadAllLines to populate a string[], then you'll pull the line you desire from the array. For the second line, pull string at index 1.

If you have the data already in a string, use string.Split(Environment.NewLine) to make the string[].

Comment: It's not a good idea to use `Environment.NewLine` as the separator in this instance -- it's the called API that decides what the line separator is, not the calling system.

Comment: That's correct, they should use whatever line separator was used in the creation of the file. It may not be Environment.NewLine.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your help. With your feedback I made this function:

```
private static string GetLineFromResponse(string response, int lineWanted)
    {
        var lines = response.Split('\n');
        return lines[lineWanted];
    }
```

Comment: This is not an answer.  Please leave thanks as a comment to the answerer.

Comment: no Odrade, this function is actually helpful. I marked the answer that helped me as the correct answer. A future google'er can find my code helpful.